# How to create a good custom DropDownList / ComboBox item in Blazor?

Tags: combobox, blazor

I want to use multiple ComboBox-Styled-Items on my Blazor-Server-App. My working code for this looks like this:

```cs
@page "/dropdownlist"
<h3>DropDownList - ComboBox</h3>

<select class="form-control col-6" @onchange="@(x => OnSelChange(x.Value.ToString()))">
    <option value="">--SelectName--</option>
    @foreach (var test in TestModelsLst)
    {
        <option value=@test.Id>@test.Name</option>
    }
</select>

@if (SelectedTestModel != null)
{
    <p>Sel TestModel-Obj.Name: @SelectedTestModel.Name</p>
}

@code {
    public TestModel SelectedTestModel;

    public void OnSelChange(string guidAsString)
    {
        SelectedTestModel = TestModelsLst.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.ToString() == guidAsString);
    }

    //---------------

    public List<TestModel> TestModelsLst = new List<TestModel>
    {
        new TestModel("Jonny"),
        new TestModel("Sarah"),
        new TestModel("Tom")
    };

    public class TestModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public TestModel(string name)
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Questions:

1.
Is there a way to pass the Class-Obj. instead of passing Guid->string->SearchinLst -> select Obj.
e.g.: `<option value=@test> @test.Name </option>` (without the valueStuff)

2.
If my code is okay. The one thing that bothers me, is that I can't figur out to use a placeholder="--SelectName--" as I did in EditForms. In my solution right now user can select the option --SelectName--.

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Is there a way to pass the Class-Obj. instead of passing Guid->string->SearchinLst -> select Obj. e.g.: 
>    @test.Name  (without the valueStuff)

Nope. The value property of the option element cannot be an object.

> 2. If my code is okay. The one thing that bothers me, is that I can't figur out to use a placeholder="--SelectName--" as I did in EditForms.
>    In my solution right now user can select the option --SelectName--.

If I understand correctly, the following might solve it (see attributes of --SelectName-- option) ...

```
<select class="form-control col-6" @onchange="@(x => OnSelChange(x.Value.ToString()))">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>--SelectName--</option>
    @foreach (var test in TestModelsLst)
    {
        <option value=@test.Id>@test.Name</option>
    }
</select>
```

Comment: :Yes that was what I was looking for. Thank you. . Overall is that the way a ComboBox should be created or is there a bigger draw back (in my code example)?

Comment: I don't see any problems with the approach you are taking.

Comment: I tried <select @onselectionchange="PickedOne" > and the event does not fire. Highly annoyed that Blazor does not have a build in combobox. Can't think of a significant application that does not need one!