# How to pass my option value to a method when the form is submitted?

Tags: c#, select, blazor-server-side

I have a `Form` which contains various components and input boxes - not relevant to the question. I want to include a select list whose options are created via a for loop which iterates through a predetermined list. I don't know how to pass on the selected option choice to method `HandleSubmit`. Not using any `javascript` just html `css` and c#.

```
   @foreach (var number in numbers)
    {
        <option value="@number">@number</option>
    }
</select>
```

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" @onclick="HandleSubmit"> @*Submits the Form*@


@code{
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
int selectedNumber;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    numbers.Add(1);
    numbers.Add(2);
    numbers.Add(3);
    numbers.Add(4);
}

private void HandleSubmit()
{

}

private void test()
{
    selectedNumber = 8;
}
```

}

which is now accessing test when an option is selected. No how do I pass in what option was selected without using jquery?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68000773/how-to-create-a-good-custom-dropdownlist-combobox-item-in-blazor

Comment: This answered my question